# How do I create a user in net-snmp C API?

Tags: c, net-snmp

I am writing an SNMP daemon in C and I want to create a user and give it read-only access. I had the following lines in the config:

```
createUser myuser SHA "12345678" AES
rouser myuser
```

How can I do the same in C from within the daemon?

Answer (score 1):

The following function does what I want. I could not find the prototype for vacm_parse_rouser() in a header file so I added it to my code.

```
void vacm_parse_rouser( const char *token, char *confline );

bool create_user_and_access()
{
    const char* username = "myuser";
    const char* auth_type = "SHA";
    char auth_pass[] = "12345678";
    const char* priv_type = "AES";
    char priv_pass[] = "12345678";
    struct usmUser* user;
    int type_nr;
    const oid* auth;
    netsnmp_priv_alg_info *pai;
    char line[128];

    user = usm_create_user();
    user->engineID = snmpv3_generate_engineID( &user->engineIDLen );
    user->name = strdup( username );
    user->secName = strdup( user->name );

    type_nr = usm_lookup_auth_type( auth_type );
    if( type_nr < 0 )
    {
        printf( "usm_lookup_auth_type %s failed.\n", auth_type );
        return false;
    }
    auth = sc_get_auth_oid( type_nr, &user->authProtocolLen );
    if( !auth )
    {
        printf( "sc_get_auth_oid %d (%s) failed.\n", type_nr, auth_type );
        return false;
    }
    user->authProtocol = snmp_duplicate_objid( auth, user->authProtocolLen );
    usm_set_user_password( user, "userSetAuthPass", auth_pass );

    type_nr = usm_lookup_priv_type( priv_type );
    if( type_nr < 0 )
    {
        printf( "usm_lookup_priv_type %s failed.\n", priv_type );
        return false;
    }
    pai = sc_get_priv_alg_bytype( type_nr );
    if( !pai )
    {
        printf( "sc_get_priv_alg_bytype %d (%s) failed.\n",
                type_nr, priv_type );
        return false;
    }
    user->privProtocolLen = pai->oid_len;
    user->privProtocol =
            snmp_duplicate_objid( pai->alg_oid, user->privProtocolLen );
    usm_set_user_password( user, "userSetPrivPass", priv_pass );

    usm_add_user( user );

    strcpy( line, username );
    vacm_parse_rouser( "rouser", line );

    return true;
}
```